# Button action not detected

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ibaction

I have the following hierarchy.

```
1. UITableView
- In cell
2. UITableView
- In cell
3. UIButton
```

The button's action isn't detected. I think it's due to nested touches.

How can I detect the action at `@IBAction`?

Comment: Show your didSelect of both tableView code

Comment: I am not detecting anything at `didSelect`. So it's unimplemented.

Comment: show your datasource code

Comment: check that tableview bounds are not covering button

Answer (score 0):

Instead of use `@IBAction` you can also set manually target to your button like below

Put below code in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method before `return cell`

```
cell.myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ClassName.FunctionName(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

And define `FunctionName` method in your relevant class.

Answer (score 0):

Aha, I got it. It turns out if the subview which contained the button (along with the other controls) had a height of 740 and the button was at a Y of 781. Moving the button up will fixed the issue. Since everything was displaying correctly, think to check the subview's height
If subview lies outside of superview then control events do not fire. For sake of convenience set clipSubviews property of the superview to YES, so that you can identify the subviews frame visually.